# Get Session from jQuery Ajax Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a method in a controller that I am calling via a jquery ajax call.

However, I am unable to get to the session information within the controller method.

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;

public class GoogleController : Controller, IRequiresSessionState

  public ActionResult GetMapPoints()
    string searchTerm = (string) Session["searchTerm"];
```

The above always returns a null object

Comment: Where are you setting the the Session?

Comment: in a different controller that's not called via an ajax call and that works fine across the other such controllers

Comment: Is GoogleController is Sessionless?

Comment: Could you provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't send the session object in your post.

You might send the session id if you are storing it in a query string. I notice you are putting a search term in a session variable, why are you doing this? You should be passing the search term as a parameter in your ajax post.

Comment: i have a good technical reason for not doing this. it's already been done and i am trying to read the session variable from with a controller action called via an ajax post.